# Help with determining if extrema exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can someone help with this from my real analysis class:

I have the transformation $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
where $$f(x,y,z)= 3/2\cdot y^2 +z^2 -(x+y)z-\cos(x) $$

I need  determine if there is a local extrema in $(0,0,0)$

I think I have to use this defintion from my book:

A function $f:A \rightarrow R$ is defined on a set $A⊂\mathbb{R}^k$, then it has a local max⁡ in the point $a \in A$,if there $∃$ a $ρ>0$ such that $f(x)≤f(a)$  for $ ∀x ∈A$ with $|x-a|<ρ$

and vice versa

---

This is what I have found out so far:

*I know that f has a stationary point in $(0,0,0)$

I have found the gradient:

$$\nabla f(x,y,z)= \begin{matrix}
\sin(x) &  -z  \\
3y  &  -z\\
2z  &  -x  & -y\\
\end{matrix}
$$ 
and the Hesse-matrix in $(0,0,0)$:

$
D^2f(0,0,0) = \begin{matrix}
1 &  0  & -1 \\
0  &  3 & -1\\
-1  &  -1  & 2\\
\end{matrix}
$

and the eigenvalues:

$\lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 2+\sqrt3, \lambda_3 = 2-\sqrt3 $

Comment: @DMcMor thank you for edit! I just edited one more sentece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the definition if you have already studied convexity/concavity and its relationship to the Hessian matrix.

If the Hessian matrix evaluated at $(0,0,0)$ has all its eigenvalues positive, which is the case, then the function is convex at $(0,0,0)$. So, if the gradient evaluated at $(0,0,0)$ has value zero, then it will be for sure a local minimum. Your gradient, evaluated at zero, has value $$(\sin(0)-0,3\cdot0-0,2\cdot0-0-0)=(0,0,0),$$ so $(0,0,0)$ is a local minimum of the function.

(All this argument is valid because $f$ is twice differentiable.)

Comment: you are right, we actually have, I just didn't think I was allowed to use that. thank you!